# How can I echo a newline in command prompt with one command?

Tags: command-line

I tried to add a new line to host file using the following command but this will add 0.0.0.0 facebook.com to the end of the last line any idea how to add with new line?

```
echo 0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com >> %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

[image]

Comment: the command added line _# ::1             localhost0.0.0.0 www.facebook.com_

Comment: is there a way of adding this line in one command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(echo. & echo 0.0.0.0 facebook.com) >> %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

The first `echo.` adds a new line, and then `&` allows you to combine it with another `echo`. When sending the results to a file like you're doing, you need to surround the grouped `echo`s with parentheses.

Comment: This seems to be adding empty lines to the host file and does the job

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the command I found the following works

```
echo.0.0.0.0 facebook.com >> %windir%/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```